# Windows Server 2012 I can't access my url from outside using IIS and IISNode

Tags: node.js, express, iis, webserver

I have a MEAN Stack application (Node.js, Angular, MySql, Express) i created some api, and i build with iis site building the iisnode.local on port 80, and add web.config with reverse proxy, but when i try to call from external browse dont open nothing

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:3000/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
            <outboundRules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
                    <match filterByTags="A, Form, Img" pattern="^http(s)?://localhost:3000/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="http{R:1}://iisnode.local/{R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

THIS IS THE DATA ON SITE BINDINGS

[image]

[image]

```
<sites>
      <site name="IISNode" id="9" serverAutoStart="true">
        <application path="/" applicationPool="IISNode">
          <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\node\mate_market\backend" />
        </application>
        <bindings>
          <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="IP-SERVER:80:iisnode.local" />
        </bindings>
      </site>
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you'll get better answers on https://serverfault.com/ .

Comment: Jones i didnt find any good solution on your link

Comment: You have to post the site bindings, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html

Comment: up you can find the site bindings data

Comment: Is there a 404 error? I suspect that the domain name of iisnode.local cannot be correctly resolved by the DNS server.

Comment: it s no error, the problem is if i don't use the host Name but only the ip work good